# Removing all the rows in a table where a subset of columns have all 0s/NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table with 30 columns. I want to remove all the rows in the table where a subset of columns have all the values in the row as either 0 or NULL. I know that I can write some query as

```sql
DELETE 
FROM Mytable
Where (col1 is NULL OR col1 = 0  ) AND
(col3 is NULL OR col1 = 0  ) AND
(col5 is NULL OR col1 = 0  )
.
.
.
many such lines.
```

Example Table (with smaller no of columns):

```
   |  col1 | col2   | col3  | col4  | col5   | col6 |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:||:---- |:------:| -----:|
R1 | 1    | 2      | 3     | 1     | 2      | 3     |
R2 | 1    |        | 0     |       | 0      |       |
R3 | 1    |        | 0     |       | 0      |       |
R4 | 1    | 2      | 3     | 1     | 2      | 3     |
R5 | 1    | 2      | 3     | 1     | 2      | 3     |
```

Let the subset of columns be {col2,col3,col4,col5,col6}.(This is just an example, there may be many such columns) . So the output of the query should be only the rows R1,R4 and R5 as R2,R3 contain either 0 or Null in the columns col2..6.

Output:

```
   |  col1 | col2   | col3  | col4  | col5   | col6  |
   |:---- |:------:| -----:||:---- |:------:| -----:|
R1 | 1    | 2      | 3     | 1     | 2      | 3     |
R4 | 1    | 2      | 3     | 1     | 2      | 3     |
R5 | 1    | 2      | 3     | 1     | 2      | 3     |
```

But I feel that the query I wrote isn't a scalable way of writing this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Show us table and index definitions.

Comment: @jarlh Sorry its specific to the work at the company and not to be disclosed. Hence used dummy values. You can assume that the column that contains primary key is not present in those subset of columns to be checked. Regarding indexes currently just I'm looking for a better way of writing the query

Comment: And show us the explain output isn't possible? How do you expect to get an reliable answer when you don't give us the information needed to assist you?

Comment: @jarlh  Sorry. I can give the example table and output. I thought the query I wrote was sufficient to understand the requirement.

Comment: @jarlh I've updated the question with a sample table

Comment: What data types are those columns? Looks like you're storing integers as literal strings, except 0, which doesn't make sense. It's confusing

Comment: @PhilCoulson updated the table. All are just numbers. My whole point was on writing the query efficiently. I just copy pasted the table from somewhere else. I apologize I didn't notice the data types.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the sum of all the columns in question equals 0. The use of `ifnull` is to turn `nulls` into `0` to allow the arithmetic operation

```
where ifnull(col1,0) + ifnull(col2,0) + ifnull(col3,0) .... = 0
```

Comment: This approach is fine, but is there any way to programmatically write this in SQL? I was wondering whether should I must write all the columns in the query.
I was hoping stg like where ifnull(col,0) for col in cols. where cols is a list of required subset of columns. I do know this is not pyhon or some other programming language tbh, but just wanted to ask what if I required to do similar operations on the same set of columns

Comment: If the subset of columns keeps changing, you'd need to look into `dynamic sql` to be able to do that, and that solutions comes with its own pains and problems.  If it's just a matter of too many columns, you're better off just hard coding them

Comment: Will this really perform better than OP's original query? I'd expect this one to be harder to optimize. (I don't know the MySQL optimizer, so I could be wrong.)

Comment: @jarlh I doubt it. There are too many columns involved for either of the solutions to avoid a table scan

Comment: Depending on data distribution, an index can be very useful. (Say most columns have lots of 0/null's, but one of them has very few. Index that column, and hope the optimizer finds the index way.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `HAVING`.

The `HAVING` clause was added to SQL because the `WHERE` keyword cannot be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: Note that no aggregate functions are involved.